# Should I add caching or not to my web app?

Tags: node.js, caching

I'm working on a node.js web app that's mainly an image based bulletin board. I read somewhere that we always need to cache since it helps improve performance, so normally I added my own caching which basically works like this: when a user visits the bulletin board the number of uploaded posts is cached, when visited again a comparison is made between the cached number and the the available number of posts, if it's the same then the cached query kicks in if not the new posts gets uploaded. Now this isn't a matter of code or anything. My code works perfectly and it does what I want it to do even if I might've explained it wrong or gave a wrong impression somehow. Problem is I read after doing all the work that caching frequently updated data is wrong and this is a bulletin board I'm talking about where users always upload images. So is it best to remove or keep the cache?

Answer (score 0):

> "There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation,
>   naming things, and off-by-one errors."
>
> — Phil Karlton

Caching depends heavily on the kind of application. Just because you've heard "caching is always better" doesn't mean you should. A good rule of thumb:

- Lean toward caching the data that is read-heavy but seldom updated.
- Have a strategy for cache invalidation on write-heavy operations.

If you believe you will be doing crazy amounts of read-writes against the same entity, consider microcaching if you're comfortable with a bit of stale data for, say, less than a minute. Just set an expiry on your cache on a minute.

If you feel like you will be benefit from serving from the cache (and, by the way, what kind of cache are you talking about? In-memory? HTTP caching? Some kind of backend, such as Redis/Memcached?), have a plan to always check cache, and if you can't find it there, serve from your data store and then cache. Then, on POST/PATCH/DELETE calls, invalidate by that key.

In the case of your bulletin board, you might want to consider invalidating cache any time someone posts or uploads anything, then cache the subsequent call. But, as I mentioned, be sure to have a strategy for invalidating.

Answer (score 0):

Adding caching makes your application more complex.  You shouldn't add it just because some random people on the internet say you should.  There are tons of situations were caching makes things better and there are other that things are made much worse.

Caching is a solution to a problem.  So what problem are you seeing? Slow client experience because of repeated downloads?  Is your server load high?  Bandwidth high?  Then perhaps you should add in some kind of caching.

Too often people hear of solutions and work towards a problem.  Identify your problems and then look into solutions.